# Reuse same instance of prototype bean twice - Spring

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a problem with Spring: I need to reuse the same instance of bean twice, but not making it singleton.

Here is a brief ApplicationContext:

```
<bean class="a.b.c.Provider" id="defaultProvider" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="lifecycle" />
    <constructor-arg ref="propertySetter" />
</bean>

<bean name="lifecycle" class="a.b.c.Lifecycle" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg ref="someParam" />
        ... and more args
</bean>

<bean id="propertySetter" class="a.b.c.PropertySetter" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="lifecycle" />
</bean>
```

So, I need to have fully initialized `Provider` with `Lifecycle` and `PropertySetter` inside,
and this `PropertySetter` must contain reference to same `Lifecycle`, as the `Provider` have.

When I define `lifecycle` and `propertySetter` as singletons, it causes big problems, because
if I create more than one `Provider`, all instances of `Provider` class shares same lifecycle
and property setter, and it's breaking application logic.

When I try to define all beans as prototypes, Lifecycles in `Provider` and in `PropertySetter` are not the same => exceptions again.

I have one solution: to pass to `Provider` only `Lifecycle` and create `PropertySetter` inside `Provider` java constructor (by extending `Provider`).
It is working well, but only in my local environment. In production code I can't extend 3pty `Provider` class, so I can't use this solution.

Please advise me, what most appropriate to do in this situation?

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this?

Comment: @DaveNewton I need to do it because of requirements. This is a small bad-designed plugin of complex application, and I can't redesign it deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extend `Provider`. Just create your own `ProviderFactory` that will take reference to `lifecycle` and will create `PropertySetter` and then `Provider`:

```
public class ProviderFactory {

  public static create(Lifecycle lc) {
    return new Provider(lc, new PropertySetter(lc));
  }
}
```

Here is Spring declaration:

```
<bean id="defaultProvider" scope="prototype" 
      class="a.b.c.ProviderFactory" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg ref="lifecycle" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented my fix this way. Greetings from Russia :)