# Re-using same instance of prototype bean created by Spring

Tags: java, spring, solid-principles

I am looking for a way to represent below code using spring dependency injection and comply to the solid principles.

```
 A a = new A();

 I b = new B(a);
 I c = new C(a);
 I d = new D(a);

 Z z = new Z( Lists.newArrayList(b,c,d));
```

B, C and D are implementations on the same interface and a list of these is required for Z instantiation. Overall, there should be one new A instance per Z creation.

None of the objects can be a singleton, and I am stuck getting this translated to a spring xml configuration.

Comment: What's blocking you?

Comment: When I define all of these as prototype beans in a context.xml then each of the b,c,d instances hold a reference to distinct instances of A. Instead they need to reference the same instance of A.

Comment: So all of B, C, D, and Z have to be prototypes? A also has to be a prototype, but the same instance should be used for all of the others?

Comment: Yes, it is similar to the question below, however, using a factory is not very clean code as I have tens of implementations of I (such as b,c,d..) which need to be wired in. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746740/reuse-same-instance-of-prototype-bean-twice-spring?rq=1

Comment: Create a wrapper class for B, C, and D which takes a single instance of A to construct the other three. Then construct Z from the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

May you try to have a configuration like this one :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class A {...}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class B implements I {

 private A a;

 @Autowired
 public B(A a) {
   this.a = a;
 }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class C implements I {

 private A a;

 @Autowired
 public C(A a) {
   this.a = a; 
 }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class D implements I {

 private A a;

 @Autowired
 public D(A a) {
  this.a = a;
 }
}


public class Z {

  @Autowired
  private List<I> implementations;
}
```

Each implementations of I inject A directly in the constructor. Z inject all implementations if I.

Comment: This way each of the objects for B, C and D obtains a different instance of A. The aim is to re-use the same instance of A

Comment: Yes, if you want to reuse the same instance of A, you have to define its scope by singleton. Just remove the scope prototype, the default scope is singleton.